# Create Gmail Draft with a HTTP Request

Tags: python, flask, gmail-api

I am trying to make a Gmail Draft with a HTTP request.

The sample below creates the draft, but its blank.

When I copy and paste the Base64 output into the APIs Explorer it works fine.

```
@app.route('/createEmail', methods=["POST"])
def createEmail():

    message = MIMEText('Hello World')
    message['to'] = 'to@email.com'
    message['from'] = 'from@email.com'
    message['subject'] = 'Subject'

    access_token = credentials.access_token
    flow = AccessTokenCredentials(access_token, 'application_name')
    http = flow.authorize(httplib2.Http())

    obj = http.request(
        uri='https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts',
        method='POST',
        body={
            'message':{
                'raw':base64.urlsafe_b64encode( message.as_string() )
            }
        },
        headers={'content-type':'message/rfc822'}
    )

    return obj[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not planning on sending any attachments, you can use the metadata url `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts` instead, which will allow you to send just the `raw`-parameter.

When your entire mail is sent as a `raw`-parameter in the body, you need to put the `raw`-parameter in a `message`-object, and the `Content-Type` is not `message/rfc822`, but `application/json`.

```
obj = http.request(
        uri='https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts',
        method='POST',
        body={
          'message': {
            'raw':base64.urlsafe_b64encode( message.as_string() )
           }
        },
        headers={'content-type':'application/json'}
    )
```

Comment: When I tried that I got the error - "Media type 'application/json' is not supported. Valid media types: [message/rfc822]"

Comment: I used the "metadata url" instead and it worked great, thank you.